# Angular CLI two bundles (one for prod, second for dev)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After ng build I get bundle files in /dist folder which I dynamically load in php file like this:

```
var inline = document.createElement('script');
        var polyfills = document.createElement('script');
        var styles = document.createElement('script');
        var vendor = document.createElement('script');
        var main = document.createElement('script');
        inline.async = false;
        polyfills.async = false;
        styles.async = false;
        vendor.async = false;
        main.async = false;
        inline.src = ./dist/inline.bundle.js";
        polyfills.src = ./dist/polyfills.bundle.js";
        styles.src = ./dist/styles.bundle.js";
        vendor.src = ./dist/vendor.bundle.js";
        main.src = ./dist/main.bundle.js";
        document.head.appendChild(inline);
        document.head.appendChild(polyfills);
        document.head.appendChild(styles);
        document.head.appendChild(vendor);
        document.head.appendChild(main);
```

but if I use ng build --prod my dev bundles are removed and replaced by other one. Is there some option to keep two types of bundles, for an instance one folder - /dist_prod with running ng build --prod command and second is /dist for dev version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use the `output-path` flag for that

```
ng build --prod -op ./dist_prod
ng build -op ./dist_dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! as simple as it is

Comment: Well, I just had to run `ng build --help`, next time try it for yourslef !

Comment: sure, I will!
btw I have one more question if you may help. I've replaced index.html with index.php, and after bundling I've got script tags with bundle files appended to index.php file. As you saw I am loading them dynamically so I don't need any changes to be made in this file. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: So what are you saying is that the bundles are added twice ? If so, two solutions : create a file `index_bis.php` that you will rename (so that the CLI doesn't find it and don't append anything to it), or remove your script appending logic (since it'salready done once)

Comment: I thought there is some way to set up config other way to prevent angular to append bundle files in index

Comment: Well I imagine you can stop the bundling, but in this case you won't have any bundle ... So probably not the best solution for you. Anyway, why would you append your bundles by hand to your file ? The index file isn't supposed to hold logic, and that's true even for PHP.

Comment: There is the reason for it, so I can't do that other way. but solution with index_bis.php is good, thanks!